# Connecting to an Ubuntu Remote Desktop from windows/mac from another network

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, ip

I am trying to create a home server that I can control from my other laptops/devices when I'm out of the house. I know that I can access the desktop using the Mac screen sharing, however i would need to be on the network and use an IP address as the connection medium. I need a way to be able to access the screen share, or remote desktop for windows, through something like a public IP or forwarded port or something along those lines. I cannot use static IP addresses since my internet provider does not support that with my plan.

is there any software that are custom designed for this?

Is there some way that i can do this through port forwarding?

I've never done anything with Ubuntu or Remote desktops so this might come off as a novice question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install TeamViewer. It works on HTTPS, you don't have to open any port to be reachable the internet, because the connection is made from controlled computer to TeamViewer site. When you log in to TeamViewer site, you will see your computer and be able to connect from anywhere, if you set your controlled computer to unattended access.